# How to call a method from within a constructor

Tags: javascript, function, methods, constructor, call

I've searched for a question like mine, but it hasn't been very helpful because everyone seems to be asking (and answering) something a bit more advanced than my query (I'm at the very bottom level of JavaScript knowledge/skills).

Here is my code:

```
function xyPoint(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.debugMessage = function(){
        document.getElementById("messageArea").innerHTML =
                "xyPoint(x, y) constructor called";
    };
}
```

I want my informative message to print automatically when I do

```
var myPoint = new xyPoint(10, 20);
```

I don't want to have to execute two statements like this:

```
var myPoint = new xyPoint(10, 20);
myPoint.debugMessage();
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just call debugMessage in the constructor:

```
function xyPoint(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.debugMessage = function(){
        document.getElementById("messageArea").innerHTML =
                "xyPoint(x, y) constructor called";
    };
    this.debugMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as: `var myPoint = new xyPoint(10, 20).debugMessage();`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/m0kbo7sy/)

Comment: The message is printed, but the variable myPoint is undefined (because the debugMessage method returns nothing). Try calling `alert(myPoint);` at the end of your script.